# Adding JButtons in for loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, jbutton, bounds

**JAVA Swing Problem**

I want to create a list of JButtons based on a list of strings, which represents the button text. 
In my first step, I collect my data for the button texts from an external text file. This data is stored in the data variable.

`List<String> data = ReadFile("texts.txt")`

Now I want to create the list of JButtons, named buttons. There I set their text and their Bounds. The Bounds are relative to the index, so the buttons are placed below each other. Finally, I add the button to the frame and to the buttons list.

```
List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
for (int index = 0; index < data.size(); index++) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText(data.get(index));
    button.setBounds(0, index*50, 100, 50);
    add(button);
    buttons.add(button);
```

But when I execute this, the last Button ends big, the first ones also disappear when I don't hover over them, but that's based on the fact, that the last button ist placed above:

[Picture of the executed script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bowLa.png)

The last button has the size of the frame, doesn't matter, if I resize the frame:

[Picture of the resized screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM7UT.png)

I hope someone can help me or tell me where I can find help. Thanks.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1):

> the last Button ends big, the first ones also disappear when I don't hover over them,

That is because by default the content pane of the JFrame uses a `BorderLayout`. When you add a component to the `BorderLayout` the button is added to the `CENTER`. However, only a single component can be added to the `CENTER`, so only the size/location of the last component added is managed by the BorderLayout.

Don't attempt to set the size/location of your components manually. It is the job of a layout manager to do this. In your case you can use a couple of panels with different layout so align your button in a column on the left. Something like:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );

for (int index = 0; index < data.size(); index++) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText(data.get(index));
    button.setBounds(0, index*50, 100, 50);
    //add(button);
    buttonPanel.add( button );
    buttons.add(button);
}

add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

Try the above code and you will notice that the buttons are all the same size, but the size keeps changing as the height of the frame changes.

So to prevent this resizing we need to allow the button to be displayed at their preferred height by using an additional layout manager:

```
//add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
wrapper.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(wrapper, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.